# clustered standard errors and missing values

Tags: r, stata, missing-data, standard-error

I have a question with regards to clustered standard errors and missing values. In particular, I would like to know how implementations of cluster robust estimators for covariance matrices in R and Stata deal with a situation where the cluster variable has missing values but is not included as a covariate in the regression model. Is there an approach that can be considered best practice for this problem?

There are several options:

1. delete rows with missing values in the cluster variable prior to fitting the model
2. delete rows with missing values in the cluster variable after fitting the model, then delete rows with missing cluster information after fitting the model and before computing the cluster standard errors
3. instead of deleting the cluster robust standard errors, create an extra group for the missings within the cluster variable (e.g. if there is one cluster with two groups 1 and 2, set all NA's to 3)

What is the best practice of dealing with this problem? R's `multiwayvcov` for example seems to go with option 3).

A brief example to clarify my question:

```
library(sandwich)
library(multiwayvcov)
library(lmtest)

data("petersen")
petersen <- petersen[1:200, ]

lm_fit <- lm(y ~ x, data = petersen)
# with multiwayvcov
no_missings_mvcov <- coeftest(lm_fit, cluster.vcov(model = lm_fit, cluster = ~firmid + year))
# with sandwich
no_missings_sw <- coeftest(lm_fit, vcovCL(x = lm_fit,cluster = ~firmid + year ))

petersen[1, "year"] <- NA
petersen[2, "firmid"] <- NA

lm_fit2<- lm(y ~ x, data = petersen)
# with multiwayvcov
missings_mvcov <- coeftest(lm_fit2, cluster.vcov(model = lm_fit2, cluster = ~firmid + year))
# with sandwich
missings_sw <- coeftest(lm_fit2, vcovCL(x = lm_fit2, cluster = ~ firmid + year ))

# Warning messages:
# 1: In rowsum.default(newX[, i], ...) : missing values for 'group'
# 2: In rowsum.default(newX[, i], ...) : missing values for 'group'
# 3: In rowsum.default(newX[, i], ...) : missing values for 'group'
# 4: In rowsum.default(newX[, i], ...) : missing values for 'group'

# compare multiwayvcov
no_missings_mvcov
missings_mvcov
# > no_missings_mvcov
# 
# t test of coefficients:
#   
#   Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept) -0.26823    0.34145 -0.7856 0.4330687    
# x            0.91004    0.23183  3.9254 0.0001194 ***
#   ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# > missings_mvcov
# 
# t test of coefficients:
#   
#   Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept) -0.26823    0.33627 -0.7977     0.426    
# x            0.91004    0.22839  3.9847 9.493e-05 ***
#   ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1


# compare sandwich 
no_missings_sw
missings_sw
# > no_missings_sw
# 
# t test of coefficients:
#   
#   Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept) -0.26823    0.34116 -0.7862 0.4326687    
# x            0.91004    0.23146  3.9317 0.0001166 ***
#   ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# > missings_sw
# 
# t test of coefficients:
#   
#   Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept) -0.26823    0.33732 -0.7952 0.4274630    
# x            0.91004    0.22963  3.9631 0.0001033 ***
#   ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1


# A closer look at preprocessing in multiwayvcov and sandwich

preprocess_clusters_mwvcov <- function(model, cluster, debug = FALSE){
  
  if (inherits(cluster, "formula")) {
    cluster_tmp <- expand.model.frame(model, cluster, na.expand = FALSE)
    cluster <- model.frame(cluster, cluster_tmp, na.action = na.pass)
  }
  else {
    cluster <- as.data.frame(cluster, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  }
  
  cluster_dims <- ncol(cluster)
  tcc <- 2^cluster_dims - 1
  acc <- list()
  
  for (i in 1:cluster_dims) {
    acc <- append(acc, combn(1:cluster_dims, i, simplify = FALSE))
  }
  if (debug){print(acc)}
  
  acc <- acc[-1:-cluster_dims]
  
  if(debug){print(acc)}
  
  if (!is.null(model$na.action)) {
    if (class(model$na.action) == "exclude") {
      cluster <- cluster[-model$na.action, ]
    }
    else if (class(model$na.action) == "omit") {
      cluster <- cluster[-model$na.action, ]
    }
    cluster <- as.data.frame(cluster)
  }
  
  if (debug) 
    print(class(cluster))
  i <- !sapply(cluster, is.numeric)
  cluster[i] <- lapply(cluster[i], as.character)
  if (cluster_dims > 1) {
    for (i in acc) {
      cluster <- cbind(cluster, Reduce(paste0, cluster[, 
                                                       i]))
    }
  }
  cluster
}

# > head(preprocess_clusters_mwvcov(lm_fit, ~firmid + year))
# firmid year Reduce(paste0, cluster[, i])
# 1      1   NA                          1NA
# 2     NA    2                          NA2
# 3      1    3                           13
# 4      1    4                           14
# 5      1    5                           15
# 6      1    6                           16

# > sapply(preprocess_clusters_mwvcov(lm_fit, ~firmid + year), class)
# firmid                         year Reduce(paste0, cluster[, i]) 
# "integer"                    "integer"                     "factor" 


# NA handling in sandwich

preprocess_cluster_sandwich <- function(x, cluster, ...){
  
  if (is.list(x) && !is.null(x$na.action)) class(x$na.action) <- "omit"
  ef <- estfun(x, ...)
  k <- NCOL(ef)
  n <- NROW(ef)
  
  ## set up return value with correct dimension and names
  rval <- matrix(0, nrow = k, ncol = k,
                 dimnames = list(colnames(ef), colnames(ef)))
  
  ## cluster can either be supplied explicitly or
  ## be an attribute of the model...FIXME: other specifications?
  if (is.null(cluster)) cluster <- attr(x, "cluster")
  
  ## resort to cross-section if no clusters are supplied
  if (is.null(cluster)) cluster <- 1L:n
  
  ## collect 'cluster' variables in a data frame
  if(inherits(cluster, "formula")) {
    cluster_tmp <- if("Formula" %in% loadedNamespaces()) { ## FIXME to suppress potential warnings due to | in Formula
      suppressWarnings(expand.model.frame(x, cluster, na.expand = FALSE))
    } else {
      expand.model.frame(x, cluster, na.expand = FALSE)
    }
    cluster <- model.frame(cluster, cluster_tmp, na.action = na.pass)
  } else {
    cluster <- as.data.frame(cluster)
  }
  
  ## handle omitted or excluded observations
  if((n != NROW(cluster)) && !is.null(x$na.action) && (class(x$na.action) %in% c("exclude", "omit"))) {
    cluster <- cluster[-x$na.action, , drop = FALSE]
  }
  
  if(NROW(cluster) != n) stop("number of observations in 'cluster' and 'estfun()' do not match")
  
  return(cluster)    
  
}

head(preprocess_cluster_sandwich(lm_fit2, cluster = ~ firmid + year))
# > head(preprocess_cluster_sandwich(lm_fit2, cluster = ~ firmid + year))
# firmid year
# 1      1   NA
# 2     NA    2
# 3      1    3
# 4      1    4
# 5      1    5
# 6      1    6
sapply(head(preprocess_cluster_sandwich(lm_fit2, cluster = ~ firmid + year)), class)
# > sapply(head(preprocess_cluster_sandwich(lm_fit2, cluster = ~ firmid + year)), class)
# firmid      year 
# "integer" "integer"
```

As you can see, the standard errors of `lm_fit` and `lm_fit1` differ, while the point estimates are the same. Note that ´sandwich´ returns an error message that is due to the missing values in the clustering variables.
The function `preprocess_clusters_mwvcov` now collects the cluster preprocessing of the multiwayvcov package. It looks like`multiwayvcov` eventually drops these missing clusters after the model is fit (option 2). This is in contrast to `reghdfe`, which, according to Arthur's answer, handles missing values in the clusters by deleting all observations with missing cluster variables prior to fitting the model (option 1).

The documentation in R's `sandwich` package states that "if the number of observations in the model x is smaller than in the original data due to NA processing, then the same NA processing can be applied to cluster if necessary (and x$na.action being available)" but is silent on how happens if the number of observations in the cluster variable is smaller than in the model x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Strategies

I'm not aware of any formal proofs for this but my feeling is that Strategy 1 is the only sound approach in general. At least when the observations are missing at random, nothing should go wrong when omitting the missings (other than potentially losing a bit of efficiency).

Strategy 2 seems to be potentially dangerous, especially if there are many missing values. I would be surprised if the covariance matrices remain consistent when they are computed from only a subset of the scores/residuals of the model on the full data set.

Strategy 3 might be ok but probably it depends on the specific application whether collecting observations with NAs in their own cluster. Hence, I wouldn't use this strategy by default.

#### R implementation

In terms of software: In principle, it is straightforward to implement Strategy 1. However, in the specific case of the R package `sandwich` it isn't. This is due to the modular design of the package: The model is fitted by the user before calling `vcovCL()` and the problem is only detected in `meatCL()` whereas the `bread()` extractor is not affected by the NAs. Therefore, we have decided to throw an explicit error message instructing the user to take care of this.

#### Illustration

In your example:

```
coeftest(lm_fit2, vcov = vcovCL, cluster = ~ firmid + year)
## Error in meatCL(x, cluster = cluster, type = type, ...) : 
##   cannot handle NAs in 'cluster': either refit the model without
##   the NA observations in 'cluster' or impute the NAs
```

Thus, you should do:

```
lm_fit3 <- lm(y ~ x, data = petersen, subset = !is.na(year) & !is.na(firmid))
coeftest(lm_fit3, vcov = vcovCL, cluster = ~ firmid + year)
## t test of coefficients:
## 
##             Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
## (Intercept) -0.30132    0.33879 -0.8894    0.3749    
## x            0.93566    0.23158  4.0404 7.659e-05 ***
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

#### Availability

This improved error handling is available starting from `sandwich` 3.0-1. At the time of writing, this is the current development version, available from R-Forge:  `install.packages("sandwich", repos="https://R-Forge.R-project.org")`. See also: https://sandwich.R-Forge.R-project.org/news/.

Answer (score 3):

Your edits make it seem like you’re more interested in how `sandwich` works. I’ll leave my `reghdfe` answer for reference.

> Is there an approach that can be considered best practice for this problem?

If you’re asking about a package to implement clusters in Stata then the answer is yes, and it's probably [`reghdfe`](http://scorreia.com/software/reghdfe/). Install with `ssc install reghdfe`.

See the [linked documentation](http://scorreia.com/software/reghdfe/), as well as ["Singletons, Cluster-Robust Standard Errors and Fixed Effects: A Bad Mix"](http://scorreia.com/research/singletons.pdf) and ["Linear Models with High-Dimensional Fixed Effects: An Efficient and Feasible Estimator"](http://scorreia.com/research/hdfe.pdf).

`reghdfe` takes the first approach, though you could implement (3) explicitly by assigning a group to the nonmissing values (i.e. `replace groupid = 9999 if mi(groupid)`)

The following verifies that `reghdfe` drops missing groups:

```
sysuse auto
count // there are 74 obs
count if !mi(rep78) // five are missing the cluster var
local notMissClusterVar = `r(N)'  
reghdfe price weight length, noabsorb cluster(rep78) 
assert `e(N)' == `notMissCluster'
```

The standard `regress` command does the same.

```
sysuse auto
count // there are 74 obs
count if !mi(rep78) // five are missing the cluster var
local notMissClusterVar = `r(N)'  
regress price weight length, vce(cluster rep78) 
assert `e(N)' == `notMissCluster'
```

> What is the best practice of dealing with this problem?

If you’re asking whether one should treat observations missing the variable you’d like to cluster on as their own cluster or drop them, then the answer I'd argue the default should be to drop them. Though this certainly depends on your data. Remember that the assumption of the clustered-standard errors sandwich estimator is infinite groups with finite observations within groups (see [Cameron & Trivedi (2005) p. 706-707](http://cameron.econ.ucdavis.edu/mmabook/mma.html). So, approach 3 seems least problematic when the number of groups is large and the number of observations missing group information is small. However, there are a lot of cases where not knowing the group may be disqualifying per se.

In your example you use the data from [Petersen (2009)](https://www.kellogg.northwestern.edu/faculty/petersen/htm/papers/standarderror.html). This is a panel of firms which he ultimately recommends clustering by individual (firm) and time-period. It seems hard to justify including observations from unknown periods or firms, even if you don’t want to cluster on firm identifier.

Of course, you could be in a situation where it makes sense to infer that the missing observations are from the same group. In this case it's an argument that you'll have to make.

Comment: Note that the `assert` statement will fail in a dataset with singletons, since `reghdfe` will drop them.